# Codekit Segmentation fault

Tags: ruby, sass, compass-sass, codekit

I'm getting the following error when trying to save in Codekit

```
/Applications/CodeKit.app/Contents/Resources/engines/oilypng/lib/oily_png/oily_png.bundle [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Anyone know what I need to fix?

**Edit**
I think it has something to do with Compass being unable to Compile. Compass is installed and everything was working up until today. I updated Codekit to version 1.6.1 today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing `compass clean` inside your project folder and then compile again.